# Proof on Preference Relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, economics

trying to work out this problem, please find the theorem, the problem and my attempt below.

*Theorem:* Let Z be a finite set and let X be the set of all non-empty subsets of Z. Let $ \ge $ be a preference relation on X (not on Z). Let A, B, C $ \in$ X and consider the following two properties of the preference relation on X:

i) If A $ \ge $ B and C is disjoint to both A and B then $ A \cup C \ge B \cup C$. Also, if A $\gt$ B  and C is a disjoint set then $A \cup C \gt B \cup C$.

ii) If $x \in Z$ and {x} > {y}  $ \forall y \in A$ then $ A \cup ${x} > A

*Problem:* Show that if there are an x, y, z $\in$ Z such that {x} > {y} > {z} then there is no preference relation satisfying both properties.

*My attempt*: If we let A = x, B = y and C = Z then all the conditions specified are satisfied, as for the properties, I get that the first one holds, and not sure about the second. Any help would be great.

Comment: What is the role of $z$ in condition ii?  Is it an element of $A$?

Comment: My apologies, that was a typo

Comment: Perhaps I am confused about what a preference relation is, but why wouldn't something like this be a counterexample:  "think of $Z$ as the set $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ and say we prefer one subset to another if the first has a larger sum." Doesn't that satisfy both your properties?